# How do I deploy an APEX class from one sandbox to another successfully?

Tags: visualforce, controller, error

I had to make a few updates to an APEX class in my development sandbox. I edited the class from the develop, apex classes menu in Salesforce, and then saved. I tested the class but am receiving the following error:

> List has no rows to assign to SObject. An unexpected error has
>   occurred. Your development organization has been notified.

The class seemed to work ok at initial testing, but now I am getting this error in all environments. I also moved the class to the config sandbox and get this error:

> action="{!resendEvent}": Unknown method
>   'Professional_Development_Event__cStandardController.resendEvent()'

The code:

```
    get {
        if (SF_Event == null) {

        //  Event_ID__c

            if (PD_Event.Event_ID__c == null) {
                SF_Event = new Event ();
            } else {
                List< Event > eventList = [

                    SELECT e.WhoId, e.WhatId, e.Subject, e.StartDateTime, e.Location, e.Id, e.EndDateTime, e.ActivityDateTime, e.ActivityDate,
                        ( SELECT Status, Response, RespondedDate, IsDeleted, Id, EventId, AttendeeId FROM EventAttendees)
                    FROM Event e
                    WHERE e.Id =: PD_Event.Event_ID__c AND e.WhatId =: PD_Event.Id
                    LIMIT 1

                ];

                SF_Event = (eventList != null && eventList.size() > 0) ? eventList[0] : new Event ();
            }
        }

        return SF_Event;
    }

    set ;
}

// Get / set methods for event attendee information (PD_Specialist)

public EventAttendee PD_Specialist {

    get {

        PD_Specialist = new EventAttendee ();

        if (SF_Event != null) {

                for (EventAttendee a : SF_Event.EventAttendees)

                {

                    if (a.AttendeeId == PD_Event.Specialist__c) {                          
                        PD_Specialist = a;                           
                    }

                }
        }           
        return PD_Specialist;
    }


    set ;

}

public PageReference acceptEvent() {
    DE_ProfessionalDevelopmentEvent_Helper.currentInstance.acceptEvent(PD_Event);
    system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, ' --- 1 controller_PDEvent --- ');
    system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, ' --- 2 acceptEvent --- ' );
    system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, ' --- PD_Event.Specialist_Response__c: '
        + PD_Event.Specialist_Response__c);
    //return null;

    //PageReference pr = ApexPages.currentPage();
    PageReference pr = new PageReference(URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().toExternalForm());

    system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, ' --- URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().toExternalForm(): '
        + URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().toExternalForm());

    //Commented out by MWT on 6.21.12
    //if(pr.getParameters().get(PORTAL_MODE_KEY) != null) {
    //  pr.getParameters().put(PORTAL_MODE_KEY, null);
    //}
    pr.getParameters().put( 'id' , PD_Event.Id);

    system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, ' --- pr.getUrl(): '
        + pr.getUrl());

    return pr;
}

public PageReference declineEvent() {
    DE_ProfessionalDevelopmentEvent_Helper.currentInstance.declineEvent(PD_Event);

    //send notification to the Contract owner when an event is declined - TCB
    DE_NotificationEmail_Helper.currentInstance.sendDeclineEmail(PD_Event, '' );

    PageReference pr = new PageReference(URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().toExternalForm());

    //Commented out by MWT on 6.21.12
    //if(pr.getParameters().get(PORTAL_MODE_KEY) != null) {
    //  pr.getParameters().put(PORTAL_MODE_KEY, null);
    //}
    pr.getParameters().put( 'id' , PD_Event.Id);

    return pr;

}

private final string PROFESSIONAL_DEVELOPMENT_TRAINER = 'Professional Development Trainer' ;
private final string PROFESSIONAL_DEVELOPMENT_ADMIN = 'Professional Development Admin' ;
private final string SALES_TEAM = 'Sales Team' ;  

public List<SelectOption> activePartnerPortalUsers {
    get {
        if (activePartnerPortalUsers == null) {
            activePartnerPortalUsers = new List<SelectOption>();
            activePartnerPortalUsers.add( new SelectOption('' , 'Please select a specialist' ));

            Profile pdtProfile = [
                SELECT p.Name , p.Id
                FROM Profile p
                WHERE p.Name LIKE :PROFESSIONAL_DEVELOPMENT_TRAINER
                LIMIT 1
            ];

            Profile pdAdminProfile = [
                SELECT p.Name , p.Id
                FROM Profile p
                WHERE p.Name LIKE :PROFESSIONAL_DEVELOPMENT_ADMIN
                LIMIT 1
            ];

            Profile Salesprofile = [ 
                SELECT p.Name , p.Id
                FROM Profile p
                WHERE p.Name LIKE :SALES_TEAM
                LIMIT 1
            ];

            if (pdtProfile != null) {
                for (User user : [
                    SELECT u.Name , u.LastName, u.Id
                    FROM User u
                    WHERE u.IsActive = true
                        AND (
                            u.ProfileId = : pdtProfile.Id
                            OR
                            u.ProfileId = : pdAdminProfile.Id
                            OR
                            u.ProfileId = : Salesprofile.Id
                            )
                        AND Id <> :PD_Event.Specialist__c
                    ORDER BY u.FirstName ASC] //changed to sort by first name instead of last name - CB 12/27/12
                ){
                    activePartnerPortalUsers.add( new SelectOption(user.Id, user.Name ));
                }
            }
            // select current specialist
            selectedActivePartnerPortalUsers = PD_Event.Specialist__c;
        }
        return activePartnerPortalUsers;
    }
    private set ;
}

public string selectedActivePartnerPortalUsers {
    get {
        return selectedActivePartnerPortalUsers;
    }
    set ;
}

public boolean isSelectedActivePartnerPortalUsersRendered {
    get ; private set;
}

public PageReference assignSpecialist() {

    string errorString = DE_ProfessionalDevelopmentEvent_Helper.currentInstance.isSpecialistSchedulable(PD_Event);

    if (errorString.length() == 0) {
        this .summary = null;
        isSelectedActivePartnerPortalUsersRendered = true ;
        isAssignSpecialistRendered = false ;
    } else {
        system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, ' --- errorString: ' + errorString);
        this .summary = errorString;
        this .severity = 'warning' ;
        //return null;
    }

    isSendEmailRendered = false ;
    system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, ' --- isSendEmailRendered: ' + isSendEmailRendered);

    //this.summary = null;
    //isSelectedActivePartnerPortalUsersRendered = true;

    return null ;
}

public boolean isSaveRendered {
    get {
        return isSaveRendered;
    }
    private set ;
}

public boolean isAssignSpecialistRendered {
    get {
        // me entry Only display the 'Assign Specialist' buttons for the
        // 'Professional Development Admin' and 'System Administrator' profiles.
        if (isAssignSpecialistRendered == null) {
            isAssignSpecialistRendered = false ;
        }
        if (PD_Event != null) {
            // if user who came on the page is a specialist assigned to the PD Event
            if (PD_Event.Specialist__c == UserInfo.getUserId()
                || PD_Event.Status__c == 'Completed'
                || PD_Event.Confirmed_Date_of_Training__c == null
            ) {
                isAssignSpecialistRendered = false ;
            } else {
                List< Profile > currentUserProfile = [
                    Select p.Name , p.Id
                    From Profile p
                    Where p.Id = :UserInfo.getProfileId()
                        And (p.Name = 'Professional Development Admin'
                        Or p.Name = 'System Administrator')
                ];

                if (currentUserProfile.size() > 0) {
                    isAssignSpecialistRendered = true ;
                }
            }
        }
        return isAssignSpecialistRendered;
    }
    private set ;
}

public PageReference showHideSaveButton() {
    if ('' != selectedActivePartnerPortalUsers || !isSelectedActivePartnerPortalUsersRendered) {
        isSaveRendered = true ;
    }

    return null ;
}

public PageReference savePDEvent() {
    PageReference pr;


    try {

        saveTrainingLoc();

        System.debug('--- Saving PD Event ' + PD_Event); 

        if (PD_Event.Specialist__c != selectedActivePartnerPortalUsers
            && selectedActivePartnerPortalUsers != null
            //&& PD_Event.Confirmed_Date_of_Training__c != null
        ) {
            string errorString = DE_ProfessionalDevelopmentEvent_Helper.currentInstance.isSpecialistSchedulable(PD_Event);

            if ('' != selectedActivePartnerPortalUsers && errorString.length() == 0) {
                DE_ProfessionalDevelopmentEvent_Helper.currentInstance.resetAllSpecialistRelatredFields(PD_Event);
                DE_ProfessionalDevelopmentEvent_Helper.currentInstance.scheduleSpecialist(PD_Event, selectedActivePartnerPortalUsers);
                //update PD_Event;
            } else {
                this .summary = errorString;
                this .severity = 'warning' ;
                return null ;
            }

            isSelectedActivePartnerPortalUsersRendered = false ;
            isSaveRendered = false ;

            pr = new PageReference(URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().toExternalForm());
        }


        Professional_Development_Event__c verificationPDEvent =
            DE_ProfessionalDevelopmentEvent_Helper.currentInstance.getByID(PD_Event.Id);

        //
               // CB - removed code to send email if training date changes  - 10/22/12
               //
        // if training date was changed or any of the training site fields have changed
        if(PD_Event.Confirmed_Date_of_Training__c != verificationPDEvent.Confirmed_Date_of_Training__c
        || PD_Event.Actual_Recipient_Group__c != verificationPDEvent.Actual_Recipient_Group__c
        || PD_Event.Training_Site__c != verificationPDEvent.Training_Site__c
        || PD_Event.Training_Location_State__c != verificationPDEvent.Training_Location_State__c
        || PD_Event.Training_Location_City__c != verificationPDEvent.Training_Location_City__c
        || PD_Event.Training_Location_Zip__c != verificationPDEvent.Training_Location_Zip__c
        || PD_Event.Recipient_Opt_Out__c != verificationPDEvent.Recipient_Opt_Out__c
        || PD_Event.Training_Location_Addr1__c != verificationPDEvent.Training_Location_Addr1__c
        || PD_Event.Training_Location_Addr2__c != verificationPDEvent.Training_Location_Addr2__c
        || PD_Event.Training_Location_Name__c != verificationPDEvent.Training_Location_Name__c

        || PD_Event.Training_Site_Room__c != verificationPDEvent.Training_Site_Room__c
        ) {
            // if training date was changed
            string specialistToNotify = PD_Event.Specialist__c;
            // if training date was cleared & changed
            if(PD_Event.Confirmed_Date_of_Training__c != verificationPDEvent.Confirmed_Date_of_Training__c 
            && PD_Event.Confirmed_Date_of_Training__c == null) {
                string inviteStatus = PD_Event.Specialist_Response__c;
                // if training date was cleared
                DE_ProfessionalDevelopmentEvent_Helper.currentInstance.resetAllSpecialistRelatredFields(PD_Event);
                // if there is a specialist which must be notified about event cancelation
                if(DI_Helper.isId(specialistToNotify)
                    && inviteStatus == DE_ProfessionalDevelopmentEvent_Helper.ACCEPTED_SPECIALIST_RESPONSE
                ) {
                    // notify specialist about event cancelation
                   // DE_NotificationEmail_Helper.currentInstance.sendNotificationAboutCancelingAnEvent(PD_Event, specialistToNotify);
                }
            } else {
                // if training date was changed
                if (PD_Event.Confirmed_Date_of_Training__c != verificationPDEvent.Confirmed_Date_of_Training__c) {
                    // if there is a specialist which must be notified about event changes
                    if(DI_Helper.isId(specialistToNotify)) {
                        string inviteStatus = PD_Event.Specialist_Response__c;
                        // clear all info about specialist and event
                        DE_ProfessionalDevelopmentEvent_Helper.currentInstance.resetAllSpecialistRelatredFields(PD_Event);
                        /*if(inviteStatus == DE_ProfessionalDevelopmentEvent_Helper.ACCEPTED_SPECIALIST_RESPONSE
                            && isCurrentUserPDAdmin
                        ) {
                            // do not send a new invite to the Specialist...instead, send a cancellation email, 
                            // clear the value for 'Assigned Specialist' and clear the Invite Status 
                            // (and all other fields related to first viewed, date accepted/rejected, etc.)
                           // DE_NotificationEmail_Helper.currentInstance.sendNotificationAboutCancelingAnEvent(PD_Event, specialistToNotify);
                        } */

                   }                     
                } 

            }
            if(pr == null) {
                pr = new PageReference(URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().toExternalForm());
            }

            update PD_Event;
        }     
    }

    catch (DmlException dmle) {

        this .summary = dmle.getDmlMessage(0);
        this .severity = 'warning' ;        
        System.debug('Error saving PD EVent: ' + dmle);
        return null ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this .summary = e.getMessage();
        this .severity = 'error' ;
        System.debug('Error saving PD EVent: ' + e);
        return null ;
    }

    return pr;
}


public boolean isSendEmailRendered {
    get {
        system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, ' --- begin - isSendEmailRendered --- ');
        if (isSendEmailRendered == null) {
            isSendEmailRendered = false ;
        }
        if (PD_Event != null
            && PD_Event.Specialist__c != null
            && PD_Event.Status__c == DE_ProfessionalDevelopmentEvent_Helper.SCHEDULED_STATUS
            && PD_Event.Specialist_Response__c != 'Accepted'
            && PD_Event.Specialist_Response__c != 'Declined'
        ) {
            if (PD_Event.Specialist__c == UserInfo.getUserId()) {
                isSendEmailRendered = false ;
            } else {
                List< Profile > currentUserProfile = [
                    Select p.Name , p.Id
                    From Profile p
                    Where p.Id = :UserInfo.getProfileId()
                        And (p.Name = 'Professional Development Admin'
                        Or p.Name = 'System Administrator')
                ];
                if (currentUserProfile.size() > 0) {
                    isSendEmailRendered = true ;
                } else {
                    isSendEmailRendered = false ;
                }
            }
        } else {
            isSendEmailRendered = false ;
        }
        return isSendEmailRendered;
    }
    private set ;
}

public string sendNotificationButtonName {
    get {
        if (PD_Event != null && PD_Event.Specialist__c != null ) {
            if (PD_Event.Send_Email_DateTime__c != null) {
                return 'Resend Invitation' ;
            } else {
                return 'Send Invitation' ;
            }
        } else {
            return '' ;
        }
    }
    private set ;
}

public PageReference sendNotification() {
    Professional_Development_Event__c verificationPDEvent =
        DE_ProfessionalDevelopmentEvent_Helper.currentInstance.getByID(PD_Event.Id);

    if (verificationPDEvent.Status__c != DE_ProfessionalDevelopmentEvent_Helper.SCHEDULED_STATUS) {
        this .summary = 'Sorry, but current event was changed. Please, reload the page.';
        this .severity = 'warning' ;
        return null ;
    } else {
        //DE_Event_Helper.sendNotificationEmail(PD_Event, null);
        DE_NotificationEmail_Helper.currentInstance.sendInvitationEmail(PD_Event, null);

        PageReference pr = new PageReference(URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().toExternalForm());
        return pr; 
    }
}

public boolean isConfirmedDateRendered {
    get {
        if (isConfirmedDateRendered == null) {
            isConfirmedDateRendered = false ;
        }
        if (PD_Event != null && PD_Event.Status__c != DE_ProfessionalDevelopmentEvent_Helper.COMPLETED_STATUS) {
            if (PD_Event.Specialist__c != null) {
                if (PD_Event.Specialist__c == UserInfo.getUserId()) {
                    isConfirmedDateRendered = false ;
                } else {

                    List< Profile > currentUserProfile = [
                        Select p.Name , p.Id
                        From Profile p
                        Where p.Id = :UserInfo.getProfileId()
                            And (p.Name = 'Professional Development Admin'
                            Or p.Name = 'System Administrator')
                    ];
                    if (currentUserProfile.size() > 0) {
                        isConfirmedDateRendered = true ;
                    } else {
                        isConfirmedDateRendered = false ;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                isConfirmedDateRendered = true ;
            }
        } else {
            isConfirmedDateRendered = false ;
        }
        return isConfirmedDateRendered;
    }
    private set ;
}


public string pdEventStatus {
    get {
        if (PD_Event != null) {
            return PD_Event.Status__c;
        } else {
            return null ;
        }
    }
    set ;
}

public string pdEventSpecialist {
    get {
        if (PD_Event != null) {
            return PD_Event.Specialist__c;
        } else {
            return null ;
        }
    }
    set ;
}

public boolean isSpecialistResponseCommentsEditable {
    get {
        if (PD_Event != null
            && PD_Event.Specialist__c != null
            && PD_Event.Specialist_Response__c != DE_ProfessionalDevelopmentEvent_Helper.ACCEPTED_SPECIALIST_RESPONSE
            && PD_Event.Specialist_Response__c != DE_ProfessionalDevelopmentEvent_Helper.DECLINED_SPECIALIST_RESPONSE
            && (PD_Event.Specialist__c == UserInfo.getUserId() || userProfile == '00ed0000000OtTt' )

        ) {
            return true ;
        } else {
            return false ;
        }
    }
    private set ;
}

public boolean isCurrentUserPDAdmin {
    get {
        List< Profile > currentUserProfile = [
            Select p.Name , p.Id
            From Profile p
            Where p.Id = :UserInfo.getProfileId()
                And p.Name = 'Professional Development Admin'
                //And p.Name = 'System Administrator'
        ];
        return currentUserProfile.size() > 0;
    }
    set ;
}

public string pdEventSpecialistResponse {
    get {
        if (PD_Event != null) {
            return PD_Event.Specialist_Response__c;
        } else {
            return null ;
        }
    }
    set ;
}

//Training Site Code - CB 12/5/12

public Professional_Development_Event__c pdEvent { get; set;}
public string trainingSiteLocs { get ;set ;}

public string legacyTrainingLocation {
    get {
        return DE_Event_TrainingSite_Helper.getLegacyTrainingLocation(PD_Event);
    }
    set;
}



public void accountChanged() {      
    //render the save button
    isSaveRendered = true ;

    if (pdEvent != null )    { 
        if (pdEvent.Training_Site__c == null) {
            pdEvent.Training_Location_Name__c =  '';
            pdEvent.Training_Location_State__c = '';
            pdEvent.Training_Location_Zip__c  =  '';
            pdEvent.Training_Location_City__c  =  '';
            pdEvent.Training_Location_Addr1__c  =  '';
            pdEvent.Training_Location_Addr2__c  =  '';
            pdEvent.Training_Site_Room__c = '';
        }

        else {
            //refresh the addresses
            refreshAddress();
        }
    }
}

public string plannedRGName {get;set;}
public Id plannedRGId {get;set;}

public void licensedRecipientChanged() {
    if (pdEvent != null )    { 
        pdEvent.Training_Site__c = pdEvent.Actual_Recipient_Group__c;
        pdEvent.Training_Site_Room__c = '';

        setPlannedRG();

        accountChanged();
    }             
}

public void refreshAddress () {    
    if (pdEvent != null )    {     
        DE_Event_TrainingSite_Helper.refreshAddresses(pdEvent);
    }
}


public void saveTrainingLoc() {
    if (pdEvent != null )    { 
        //save Training Site Info
        PD_Event.Training_Site__c = pdEvent.Training_Site__c;   
        PD_Event.Training_Location_State__c = pdEvent.Training_Location_State__c;
        PD_Event.Training_Location_City__c = pdEvent.Training_Location_City__c;
        PD_Event.Training_Location_Zip__c = pdEvent.Training_Location_Zip__c;
        PD_Event.Training_Location_Addr1__c = pdEvent.Training_Location_Addr1__c;
        PD_Event.Training_Location_Addr2__c = pdEvent.Training_Location_Addr2__c;
        PD_Event.Training_Location_Name__c = pdEvent.Training_Location_Name__c;

        PD_Event.Training_Site_Room__c = pdEvent.Training_Site_Room__c;
        PD_Event.Actual_Recipient_Group__c = pdEvent.Actual_Recipient_Group__c; 
        PD_Event.Planned_Recipient_Group__c = plannedRGId;
        PD_Event.Recipient_Opt_Out__c = pdEvent.Recipient_Opt_Out__c;
    }
}

public void optOutChanged() {
    isSaveRendered = true ;
    setPlannedRG();
}

private void setPlannedRG () {
     if (pdEvent.Recipient_Opt_Out__c == false) {
        Account [] getActName = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :pdEvent.Actual_Recipient_Group__c];   
        if (getActName.size() > 0) {       
            plannedRGName =  getActName[0].Name;
            plannedRGId =  pdEvent.Actual_Recipient_Group__c;
        }
        else {
            //if Actual RG is blank then set Planned RG to NULL
            plannedRGName = '';
            plannedRGId = null;
        }
     }
 }  
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add line numbers to the code so I can point out the specific lines I changed?

Comment: Have you looked at the debug logs to see what line the exception is being thrown? I suspect you don't have a profile called Sales Team in your other orgs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check on your queries if they're returning a row, a workaround I've read involves the assignment to an array.

Try to use this for reference - http://theenforcer.net/2009/09/list-has-no-rows-for-assignment-to-sobject/

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I have solved error 1. Daniel you were right, it turned out I left an 's' of of Sales Teams. I am still getting the second error. The class works in my dev org, but when I push the class to config I get an error. I am going to try to manually edit the code in config in the same manner I did in my dev org to see if that makes a difference...

Comment: It works when I make the changes in the Apex Class manually in my config sandbox. Why is the Apex Class not pushing correctly in a change set? @Daniel

Comment: Had another look at the code and noticed that the function in one of your errors wasn't defined - resendEvent(), Error action="{!resendEvent}": Unknown method 'Professional_Development_Event__cStandardController.resendEvent()'. Other functions such as savePDEvent() are.

Comment: List has no rows to assign to SObject. An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified. - For this, I would check on all your list queries and do a comparison between your orgs, there's something preventing you from doing the same list query in another org as certain fields or conditions may not be present in the other. For example, in your dev org, you're able to query events with a location custom field that is a picklist set to a certain region while your production org doesn't even have that field.

Comment: Thanks Phil. I am going to look into your comments regarding the undefined error. It is strange because I only receive this error when I move the class in a change set, but not when I make code changes manually in the environment. Do you have any idea why this might be?

Comment: I would assume that you get the error while trying to deploy the code from a change set, which would be what you mean as moving a class in a change set. If so, try doing this again, deploy the code and copy paste the exact error here.

Comment: No, the change set validates and deploys correctly. The error happens when I click on the tab for the object the class affects. The Visualforce page for that object doesn't load. I checked in the Visualforce page and the class but I can't find the standard controller and the resendEvent() it is referencing. See screenshot above.

Comment: It's the definition of functions in your class, the resendevent() is missing, unlike these other ones which are there, acceptEvent(), etc.